# How can I abort/pause/continue the execution of an thread or function without a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt

I have an application using PySide, this application will execute some long processes(without a loop) and i need to can abort/pause/continue the execution of this process that is running in a different thread(to prevent freezing the GUI).
This application launch SAP and execute the automation selected, but I didn't find any solution to pause/continue or abort without the process is in a loop.
I have a button that when is clicked, connect to a function that instance an Thread Class and gives the object of the process class, then the thread class instances the object and starts the function
that have about 3k-5k lines of an long automation.
Some example created to illustrate:

Pages_Core

```
class PageProcess(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        mainObject = QHBoxLayout(self)
        mainObject.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        mainObject.setSpacing(5)
        frameLeft = CustomFrame(orientation="vertical")
        self.leftData = frameLeft.layoutObject

        mainObject.addWidget(frameLeft, stretch=1.9)
    
    def add_ProcessButton(self, thisObject: object):

        button = QPushButton(text="Start")
        self.leftData.addWidget(button)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.previewProcess(button, thisObject))
        return button
    
    def previewProcess(self, button, thisObject: object):

        if button.isChecked():
            self.lastButton = button
            self.__testProcess(thisObject)
            button.setText("Cancel")
            
        else:

            #
            #
            #--------HERE IS THE ABORT CALL
            #
            #
            #

            button.setText("Start")
            button.setChecked(False)
    
    def __testProcess(self, thisObject):
        
        self.runObject = thisObject()
        self.thisWorker = Thread(target=self.runObject.runTest)
        self.thisWorker.start()
```

PageExample

```
from core.Pages_Core import *
from scripts_lib.test import Test

class SAPTestExample (PageProcess):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_ProcessButton(thisObject=Test)
```

Test

```
from core.qt_core import *


class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        somevars = None
    def runTest(self):
        print("Do something with 3K-5K lines")
```

I already tried search in various sites to understand more about threading, watched a ton of videos, and ask several people in groups but all starts with the premise of the loop. I tried too use QThread but without success.
Basically, I need to abort/pause/continue the thread or the function that have the automation.

Comment: You already know the answer. It's impossible. If you use a worker process, you can suspend, resume, and terminate the child process. (It depends on the OS. In Linux, you can use the SIGSTOP, SIGCONT, SIGTERM/SIGKILL.)

Comment: @relent95 I searched for many days and i think that i have to implement a function to check every single time if the control variable is True when i exec the base functions  and i saw that i have to set the process inside of an try, because i can raise an error and exit the process. For now its what i did, but if exist a different way, i want to know :/